# How to restore GLIBCXX_3.4.20?

Tags: apt

apt-get no longer works. When I try anything with it, I get the error

> apt-get: /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.4/lib/lnx64.o/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12)

Googling a way to fix this lead me to threads saying I should use apt-get to restore that file, but obviously that won't work in my case because apt-get is the thing that's not working. What should I do?

Comment: Have you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or modified `/etc/ld.so.conf` or added an entry to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` to point to the Xilinx directory?  It seems this third-party library is overriding the OS provided stdc++ library and was compiled against a different version of glibc.

Comment: So if I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH back to what it's supposed to be things should work again? How do I find out what the path is supposed to be, or what the ld.so.conf is supposed to look like? Is there a reference somewhere?

Comment: Just `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to reset it to the default.

Comment: Oh wow, that was super easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(based on comments)

You have overridden the default library resolver path so that the stdc++ library is being called from the Xilinx directory, rather than the OS default.  This library appears to be compiled against a different version of glibc.

You need to `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to ensure the `apt-get` command only looks for the standard OS libraries.